# How to select only decreasing delta in values with increasing delta also present in data?

Tags: sql

I have a warehouse which returns stock. Stock diminishes (orders) and increases (supplies). I have only stock values, nothing else. Say I have this data sorted by stock quantity ascending:

| time | stock |
| --- | --- |
| 00:11 | 7144 <--- current |
| 00:10 | 7280 |
| 00:09 | 7416 <--- note increase, means new supply arrived |
| 00:08 | 2259 |
| 00:07 | 2333 |
| 00:06 | 2538 |
| 00:05 | 2999 |
| 00:04 | 3074 |
| 00:03 | 3104 <--- start |

I need to derive orders excluding supply, so max(qty)-min(qty) do not work, function has to mind the sudden increase and return only diminishing delta. So I expect in given values formula to be: `orders = (3104-2259)+(7416-7144)`

How would you approach this task?

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: But I use both of them simultaneously, postgresql and clickhouse via foreign wrapper.

Comment: By what is your sample data ordered? ```id```? Or some ```timestamp``` column? Please add this column to the sample data and include the column names there as well.

Comment: @Islingre it is timestamp. I thought my comment (start-current) made sence. I added some virtual time for you. Duration and time step doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can join two "adjacent" rows and check that the `stock` of the earlier row is more than the `stock` of the later row to find your orders. Then sum over the difference of these stocks.

Assuming that the column `time` is unique, you can use following query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(t1.stock - t2.stock) AS sum_of_orders
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.time > t1.time
                            AND NOT EXISTS(
                                SELECT 1
                                FROM my_table t3 
                                WHERE t3.time > t1.time AND t3.time < t2.time)
WHERE t1.stock > t2.stock;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can identify the "islands" by when the stock increases.  Then within each island you want the max and min.  You can summarize the islands using:

```
select min(stock), max(stock)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_stock > stock then 0 else 1 end) over (order by time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(stock) over (order by time) as prev_stock
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Then one more summary gives the total you want:

```
select sum(max_stock - min_stock)
from (select select min(stock) as min_stock, max(stock) as max_stock
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when prev_stock > stock then 0 else 1 end) over (order by time) as grp
            from (select t.*,
                         lag(stock) over (order by time) as prev_stock
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      group by grp
     ) t;
```

Here is a db<>fiddle.